# Why does a MooseX::App app not know any commands on a different machine

Tags: perl, command-line-interface, moose

I have written a midsized CLI application. Once I copied it to our development server I noticed it doesn't recognize or know any of its commands if run there. I minimized the code to the following example which works in my local machine but not on the server. What cloud be the reason?

```
package MyApp;
use MooseX::App;

1;

package MyApp::Yay;
use MooseX::App::Command;

sub run {print "yay\n"}

1;

package main;

MyApp->new_with_command->run;

1;
```

Save that in a file `my_app.pl` and call it like:

```
perl my_app.pl yay
```

Expected output:

```
yay
```

On the development server the little application doesn't accept `yay` as a command nor does it list any command in the help. The output looks like this:

```
Unknown command 'yay'
usage:
    my_app.pl <command> [long options...]
    my_app.pl help
    my_app.pl <command> --help

global options:
    --help -h --usage -?  Prints this usage information. [Flag]

available commands:
    help  Prints this usage information
```

The software involved is:

- local machine (working)

  - Perl v5.14.4
  - MooseX::App 1.30
- development server (not working there)

  - Perl 5.10.0
  - MooseX::App 1.30

Unfortunately I cannot install different Perl versions on the development server but <del>I doubt it's related to Perl itself</del>. *Update:* It actually turned out that Perl 5.10.0 broke `MooseX::App`.

Does the program know the `yay` command when you execute it? Do you have any hint why it won't work?

Comment: Works for me in 5.10.1 with MooseX::App 1.30. 5.10.0 was kind of buggy and is pretty unusual to still be using at this point.

Comment: install 5.10.0 on the local machine and try it (see perlbrew); you may find it's not the perl version but the version of some other module?

Comment: @AKHolland, you're right: I installed Perl 5.20.1 with perlbrew and it worked. If you post an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @ysth, perlbrew was a good hint but 5.10.0 wasn't available for me. I rather tried to use a newer Perl on the development server which also led to success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5.10.0 was a fairly buggy version of perl. Try another version using perlbrew.